# how do I get a new line, after using float:left?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is have rows of images, 6 images in each row.  Some of these images need to have another image floating on top of them (flush with the lower-right corner). I was able to get that to work from this thread:

[How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

However, now I'm unable to get the new row after the 6th image. Neither `<BR>` or `<P>` create a new line. They simply push the next image down several pixels, but the image is still in the same line. It seems like the float style is interfering with the `<BR>` and/or `<P>`.

I tried using different styles for the image that starts a new row, like `float:none` and `display:block`, but neither worked. The odd thing is that the new line starts **after** the 7th image.

Here's what I'm using so far:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; } 
.containerdivNewLine { float: none; display: block; position: relative; } 
.cornerimage { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; } 
</style>

<div class="containerdiv">
  <img border="0" height="188" src="myImg" width="133" />
  <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="imageOnTop" width="105" />
</div>
```

For the 7th image, when I'm trying to start a new row, I'm simply replacing the 'containerdiv' class with 'containerdivNewLine'.

Comment: If possible, you might try using the class `"containerdiv NewLine"` instead of `"containerdivNewLine"`. That way, you can just use the compound style `div.containerdiv.NewLine { clear: left }` instead of repeating the `position: relative;` and other common styles from `div.containerdiv`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to "clear" the float after every 6 images. So with your current code, change the styles for `containerdivNewLine` to:

```
.containerdivNewLine { clear: both; float: left; display: block; position: relative; }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! However, I also have 'normal' content (text and a couple small images that flow next to each other fine w/out styling) which I want to include between rows of images, and this is not working with that 'normal' content. However, I didn't mention that in the original question. Any ideas on that? I tried using simple <div style="display:none"> on these areas, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The normal text will need to have `clear: both` on it as well, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks again. I need a little spacing between sections but I'll try to work that one out.

Comment: Good Solution !

Answer (score 63):

you can also use

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

Comment: This one worked for me, i don't know why it didn't worked directly on the CSS file...  maybe there's another directive inside such spaghetti code, not mine :D

Answer (score 4):

Try the [clear](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_clear.asp) property.

Remember that float removes an element from the document layout - so yes, in a way it is "interfering" with `br` and `p` tags, in the sense that it would basically be ignoring anything in the main flow layout.

Answer (score 4):

Also such way

```
<br clear="all" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that's a little more semantic is to have a UL defined as your total 6 image width, each LI defined as float left and width defined - so that when LI #7 hits, it runs into the boundry of the UL, and is pushed down to the new row.  You'll still have an open float that you'll want to clear after the /UL - but that can be done on the next element of the page, or as a clear div.  Here's sort of the idea, you may have to mess with actual values, but this should give you the idea.  The code is a little cleaner.

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
ul#imageSet { width: 600px; margin: 0; padding:0; }
ul#imageSet li { float: left; width: 100px;  height: 188px; margin: 0; padding:0; position: relative; list-style-type: none; }
.cornerimage { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; } 
h3.nextelement { clear: both; }
</style>


<ul id="imageSet">
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
        <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </li>
</ul>


<h3 class="nextelement">Next Element in Doc</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table.

```css
table {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="img-container">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#" <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img href="#">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img border="0" height="188" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2459/3534790964_5d8bed17c0.jpg" width="100" />
      <img class="cornerimage" height="140" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3310/3514664446_08e9745681.jpg" width="50" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`tr` - Table Row
`th` - Table Header (basically one grid)