# How do I lay a div tag on top of div tag

Tags: image, html

Anyone know how to lay a div tag that has an Image in it on top of a other div tag that has its one image in it? In the end I want to lay one image on top of a other image.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do two div tags, one housing the other, both with background images applied to them. Then you can use the background-position to position them how you'd like.

```
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
</div>

#one{background:url('image_one.png') no-repeat}
#two{background:url('image_two.png') no-repeat}
```

**EDIT:** Make sure you set the height and width of the `div`'s to match your image size.

Answer (score 0):

Put a background image in the bottom `<div>` tag, and put an `<img />` inside the div. Another possibility is to use 2 `<img>` tags, but apply `Position:absolute` to both and use `z-index` to specify the layer order.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up as a nested div with the internal div set to use relative positioning.

The following is the best tutorial I've ever seen on css positioning:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
    <img src="foo.png" />
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute:top:0;left:0;">
    <img src="bar.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

solution 2:

```
<div style="background:url('foo.png') no-repeat scroll transparent">
  <img src="bar.png" />
</div>
```

not great solutions...  Not sure why you would want to do this anyway