# Circle div with information, on hover show all information

Tags: css, html, hover, geometry

I want to have three circular divs next to each other (that's not a problem). At the bottom of the circle it will show the first words of my information text. On hover the information text will go up so you can read the whole text:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zIbG27h.png]

What I tried to do at first was to create a div `width: 170px` and `height: 170px`, set a circle as a background in my CSS and do `class:hover` to bring up the text.

What I realised while attempting this was that I can't hide some of the text "behind" the circle like in the *Normal* picture I posted above.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Heres another image better explaining how I mean:
http://i.imgur.com/zIbG27h.png

Answer (score 0):

Make an `img` that floats on top of the text (using CSS absolute positioning) that has the inner part of the circle transparent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997397/1979005) for more information.

Comment: Hi Math. Thank you for your answer. I'm yet to figre out how to do this as I don't really understand what you mean. Could you possible explain again? I'm trying to figure out what to do with the link you gave me.

Comment: Create an image that is just like the existing circle, but with the center transparent. Then, follow the method above to position it on top of the original `div` with CSS absolute positioning.