# How to overlay one image on another

Tags: css, image, overlay

I don't think this can be done but would appreciate confirmation either way.

I have a product image on my store that uses code like this, which I cannot edit

```
<div class="product"><a href="productpage.php"><img id="productimage0" class="productimage" src="images/prod.jpg" style="border:0" alt=" " /></a></div>
```

That gives me the product image and a link to the information page. What I would like to do is add a graphic on top of that product image showing that it is 20% off this week. I could make just one image with the text included but as the discounts will change I'd prefer to have a more dynamic way of doing things.

I was hoping to do this via css but really don't know how.

I can't alter the source code on the page but can edit the css file.

Thanks for reading

Albrecht

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html may be helpful

Comment: Can you use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: @Aravind30790: That's not really too helpful as the OP can't edit the HTML (for whatever weird reason)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks  Theoretically I could edit the code but as soon as the software is updated it would be overwritten meaning I'd need to put back the modification each time. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: If you CAN'T add atleast something into that markup ..then no. Now if your allowed to use javascript I could give you a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Starboy -if I need to edit the code the simplest solution may be the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html - I didn't think this was going to be possible without code edits and I'll now have to decide whether it's worth the hassle or not.

Comment: There must be a way to customize your package built into the software, which package are you usinG?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QHFWf/2/

HTML

```
<div class="product">
    <a href="productpage.php">
        <img id="productimage0" class="productimage" src="images/prod.jpg" style="border:0" alt=" " />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    background:eee;
}
.product img {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;    
}
.product img:after {
    content: "20% Off!";
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:3;
    color:#fff;
    background:#c00;
}
```