# In Play Framework, how to put an image on top of another?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to Play.
I'm wondering how to put an image on top of another.
I used this method

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="a.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
  <img src="b.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 30; left: 70;"/>
</div>
```

from [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

But running on Play, it just didn't work.
The images are positioned side by side, and changing the "top" and "left" value didn't make any difference.

And I ran the static html file with static path to image, it worked.
I'm quite confusing right now.

I'm using Play 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any reason to blame Play as in your case it doesn't even generate the code just displays it...

Add unit to the non-zero values, that should help.

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="a.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
  <img src="b.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: yeap, 0-values can also use the units, anyway that's redundant (modern IDEs highlight it as an error). The most important is that non-zero vals REQUIRES the units.