# how to put buttons over an image by their coordinates and run jquery function when clicking on these buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in which I put an image in png format. For the image I have a set of points with their coordinates x1, y1. I need to put some kind of buttons (for example, with width=18 and height=23) over the image and locate them according to their coordinates. When the user clicks on a button, I want alert() function run. How can I do it? When the user will resize the window, the image would also resize, so the coordinates should be recalculating to be appeared on the right place.

Comment: you should set the anchor property

Comment: use absolute position and percentage for top and left

Comment: I've found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `<map>` tag, specifically called *image-map*.

**Example**:

```
 <img src="https://ctd.ucsd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ABCD_VotingCard.png" usemap="#map"/>
  <map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="8,8,132,100" title="A" onclick="alert('A')">
    <area shape="rect" coords="158,8,282,100" title="B" onclick="alert('B')">
    <area shape="rect" coords="8,124,132,216" title="C" onclick="alert('C')">
    <area shape="rect" coords="158,124,282,216" title="D" onclick="alert('D')">
  </map>
```

Here's a <kbd>**[demonstration](http://jsbin.com/miracucebewa/1/edit)**</kbd>.