# bootstrap3:/ two images responsive together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

with Bosstrap3/.
I have 2 image. One image is big. another is small.

both of image are responsive.

I want put small image on big image.

It's easy for a static page. But I want do it for a responsive page.

I want position of images not be change with resize of page.

I try this:

```
<div class="container">

<div class=" panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:1px">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1170x300" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>Bootply Editor &amp; Code Library</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<img class="img-responsive mytumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000">
```

AND css code:

```
.mytumb{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:40px;

}
```

But it works for an static page.

How can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18935/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go here for a solution [position one image above another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html) , you will surely get a solution. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `image` inside your `.container div` so it is in `absolute` position `relative` to this `container`.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18938/)

And then, play with **media queries** to make it fits everytime.

```
.container { position: relative; }
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .img-responsive.mytumb { width: 20%}
}
```

It is not perfect but you've got the idea I suppose.