# How to set an image on top of another image?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

Images should be responsive for all devices. 
I used

```
    <img src="images/enter/red20.png" class=" img-responsive" 
        style="max-width:15%;position: absolute; right: 30%;"/>
    <img src="images/enter/computer.png" class=" img-responsive" />
```

on first top image but when is change the size or browser top image moves at other place. see design in above link.

Comment: show code or jsfiddle

Comment: I edited see code now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Comment: That image doesn't look very helpful to me, what do you desire exactly? Must the images move relative, independent, not at all? How do you want to position them over each other?

Comment: but i need responsive for all devices.

Comment: i want first image should be on top right corner of second image. and responsive for all devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use percentages in combination with max-width.

The big image, you give it a max-width: 100%, therefor it will never be bigger as it own size, but also won't it be bigger as it's parent.

Wrap that image in a parent div. This div becomes a display: inline-block, so I will be as width as it's content. You place this div relative.

Then we add the little image inside the div and place it absolute. It's position then will be relative to the parent (div) and not the body. Give it a max-width of 25% (for example) and give it a top and left/right position in %.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="big-img" src="big.png" />
  <img class="small-img" src="big.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.big-img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.small-img{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 25%;
  max-width:25%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uu3pqwpa/)

Make the result window smaller and you'll see the images resize.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="big-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DATNq.png" />
  <img class="small-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DATNq.png" />
</div>
```

css make wrapper `position-relative;`

```
.wrapper{
  position-relative;
}
.big-img{
  width:300px;
}
.small-img{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:172px;
  max-width:70px;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsk1hssw/3/)

Comment: this is not responsive. when i resize the window of browser first image moves to another place

Comment: @SohaibRiaz max-width:100%; put this in the .big-img

Comment: for mobile left: 172px; will be best but for desktop left:172;  will not enough to make it responsive. like i want to put these images in center of div. so if device changed image position will be changed also. i want these images at the center of all resolution

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an image editing software to combine the two images? This solves a lot of problems related to positioning. You can then scale the image in different sizes and then use those for different page layouts, e.g.

1. "imageName-original"
2. "imageName-1/2x"
3. "imageName-2x"
4. "imageName-4x

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first Image in background of a relative div if possible. And second as an absolute image in div.
Thanks