# How can I overlay logo over a image? using css

Tags: html, css

As you can see the logo is displayed above the background-image, but i would like it to be in the center of the background image.

this is my header and the background needs to begin on top of the page and end before the menu. the logo needs to be displayed in the center over the background image.
i have tried a lot but maybe somebody had a similar problem and can help me with this.

[image]

this image show the thats its almost working but its behind the background

```html
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=font1|font2|etc' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="navbar.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--bootstrap--> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="styles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!--datepicker -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="styles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>  

</head>
<body>
<header>
  
  
  <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <img class="logo" src="fts.png">
  
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
              
          </li>
          <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
              
          </li>
          <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
              
          </li>          
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
              <div class="slide1">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 <div class="item">
              <div class="slide2">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
          </div>
      </div>   
 <div class="item">
              <div class="slide3">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
          </div>
 </div></div>
          
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel"  data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> </span></a>
          
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel"  data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span> </a>         
  </div>
</header>
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-right">
  <ul>
  <?php
    switch ($_SESSION['isAdmin']) { 
                case "1":
                echo '<li><a href="adminDash.php"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i><span>AdminDash</span></a></li>' ;
                break;

                case "0":
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }

?>
     <li><a href="index.php"><span>DASHBOARD</span><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="acties/nieuwTicketDash.php"><span><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> NIEUW TICKET</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="tickets.php"><span>ALLE TICKETS</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="klanten.php"><span></i> KLANTEN</span></a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="acties/uitloggen.php"><span><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>UITLOGGEN</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <br><br><br>
</body>

<style>
body {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
   
}

img.logo {
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
  
  /* Carousel Styling */
.carousel div[class^=slide] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1
}

.slide1{
  background-image: url('styles/3.jpg');
}
.slide2{
  background-image: url('styles/2.jpg');
}
.slide3{
  background-image: url('styles/1.png');
}
</style>
  </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position:relative/absolute`

```css
img.logo {
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Carousel Styling */

.carousel div[class^=slide] {
  height: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1
}
.slide1 {
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/500');
}
.slide2 {
  background-image: url('styles/2.jpg');
}
.slide3 {
  background-image: url('styles/1.png');
}
```

```html
<header>


  <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <img class="logo" src="//placehold.it/100/FF0">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">

      </li>
      <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1">

      </li>
      <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2">

      </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="slide1">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="slide2">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="slide3">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> </span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span> 
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: i tried your method but i think the image is not displayed in front however if i  make the background smaller the bottom of the logo appears. the background is overlaying the the logo now.

Comment: you tried to edit my answer, you need to edit **your** question

Comment: edit must be reviewed, but your codes worked almost it is only displaying behind the background so only the logo must be displayed over the background. the postioning is good.

Comment: i found it!, you put the background on z-index-1; and i putted the z-index logo on 1 and is working thanks

Comment: are you setting the `z-index: -1` on the background ?

Comment: yes but there was no z-index inon the logo so i putted the logo z-index: 1; and it worked! thanks man