# How To Add An Image Above Another using PHP

Tags: php, image

I Have A Background Image Now I want PHP to Put Another Image On Top Of It (The Other Image Is Stored in A Variable)
Example variable $x
& My Background Image Is Also A Variable $back
Example ../img/back.jpg
Now i wish to Add The $x On The Left side of The Background
How May I Achieve this?
Like In This Pic There is The Green Part with a Shadow Image
How Can I replace that PART with another Picture using PHP?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjK0o.jpg)
What i Have so Far

```
<?php
copy("https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/picture?width=99&height=99", "picture.jpg");
$x =  "picture.jpg";
copy("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjK0o.jpg","bg.jpg");
$back = "bg.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: See `imagecopy()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php and all the other copy functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Comment: @Andreas I don't think it's a duplicate. The OP want the output to be an image, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Combining images is part of image processing. You can use the [gd library](http://php.net/gd) directly. However I recommend using an OO image processing library like [intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/), which is easier to write and understand.

```
// open the background image file
$img = Image::make('bg.jpg');

// Add the facebook image
$img->insert('picture.jpg');

// Save the image as a new file
$img->save('newpicture.jpg');
```

Read the documentation about the [insert method](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert) to understand how to position the facebook image.