# Overlap with top image CSS

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I need to create `ion-card` as shown below. I have tried many ways. But no luck yet. Any clue?

**Note:** It has 2 images. top one and small book cover.

Here is the sample of [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-i29aua?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

**This is what I need:**

[image]

*.html*

```
<ion-card class="card-margin">
    <img class="contentPicture" [src]="data?.image" />

    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-item class="book-cover">
            <ion-thumbnail item-left class="thumbnail">
                <img [src]="data?.image2">
            </ion-thumbnail>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="book-details">
            <h2>From book:
                <span>My book</span>
            </h2>
            <h2>Publisher:
                <span>My publisher</span>
            </h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html

Comment: use z-index and position absolute to solve

Comment: I need to do it with `ion-card`. @MohanGopi

Comment: yes try once with the above stack link it will work even with ion-card

Comment: Hope you'll simulate it on above stackblitz. It is not that much easy with `ion-card` for me.Hope you'll try that and let me know. @MohanGopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dmdajc?file=pages/home/home.scss).

Set styles in `.book-cover` class:

```
.book-cover{
  top: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Note: You may have to edit the image's alpha to remove the whitespace in the image itself if you have any.

For the name section, I suggest using `ion-row` and `ion-col` instead of `ion-item` as the latter takes up the entire row.

```
<ion-card-content>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-2 class="book-cover">
                <ion-thumbnail item-left class="thumbnail">
                    <img [src]="data?.image2">
                </ion-thumbnail>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="book-details">
                <h2>From book:
                    <span>My book</span>
                </h2>
                <h2>Publisher:
                    <span>My publisher</span>
                </h2>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    <ion-grid>
    </ion-card-content>
```

Comment: OK, Can I have help for the `book-details` section too?

Comment: updating my answer

Comment: @Sampath above will work but image thumbnail needs to be resized based on responsiveness..

Comment: That is it. Thanks a lot :) The trick was `ion-row`. One question: Is that OK to use `ion-row` without `ion-grid`?

Comment: Hmmm.. OK. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sampath `ion-grid` is only used to add some padding to the rows, or if you need to wrap the rows inside of a container in order to apply some CSS style rules to the wrapper. But that's all, most of the time I've used `ion-row`'s without the `ion-grid` wrapper

Comment: Oh.. That is great info. Thanks a lot. After a long time :) @sebaferreras

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` to the main image and `position: absolute` to the book image here I did sample code

```css
.bg-image {
  position: relative;
  
}
.book {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/U4Oadyu.png">
</div>
<div class="book">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/r7uK5St.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text">
<p>Text Here</p>
</div>
```