# Mouseover not working when element above target element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning about mouse events. At the moment, my goal is to have [2 images on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html). For example, you move the mouse over an image and see a pop up. When you move the mouse away, the pop up goes. I think this is quite a common thing.

Because I have an image in front of the other, my research suggests I need to use `mouseleave`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_leave_out

The problem I have is that I get a flickering effect as I try to hide or remove the hide class (which makes the image visible or not)

This snippet shows everything

```js
var inst = document.getElementById("instrument");
inst.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  toggleEdit(true);
})
inst.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  toggleEdit(false);
})
var edit = document.getElementById("edit");
var i = 0;

function toggleEdit(isShow) {
  console.log(i++);
  edit.className = edit.className.replace(" hide", "");

  if (!isShow) {
    edit.className += " hide";
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background: green;
}

.image1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.image2 img {
  max-width: 20px;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image1" src="https://placehold.it/100" id="instrument" />
  <a id="edit" href="#" class="image2 hide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/06/00/33/edit-icon-2375785_960_720.png" /></a>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8jvjazuh/)

How do I prevent this flickering?

Comment: You don't need JS at all for that. It can be achieved just with CSS using `:hover`.

Comment: ... it can @JeremyThille? I didn't think a hover event on an element could affect the style of another element in CSS?

Comment: Most popups aren't actually different elements or images moving over the other. As Jeremy says, they're just changes in css so the element never changes.

Comment: There's adjacent children selectors in css. Otherwise put the hover event on the parent element of both elements. `parent:hover childIdentifier`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need JS at all for that. It can be achieved just with CSS using `:hover`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background: green;
}
.parent:hover .image2{
    visibility: visible
}

.image1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image2 img {
  max-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image1" src="https://placehold.it/100" id="instrument" />
  <a id="edit" href="#" class="image2">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/06/00/33/edit-icon-2375785_960_720.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been using CSS for years and never realised I could put the :hover at that position.... I've only ever done :hover as the last entry. This is amazing

Comment: Imagine what you will know tomorrow :) Also, please don't forget to validate the answer if you think it's worth it.

Comment: Fair enough then.

Comment: Whilst this doesn't answer the question, I get the feeling that I'm probably using the wrong technology for what I'm doing - CSS is the better choice, as such I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score -1):

That seems like the expected behaviour to me. Once you have your mouseover the small image, then theoretically it is not over the big image so that why the small image disappears. And when that happens the mouseover effect is triggered again on the big image, putting it in a "loop". You could add the same logic to your small image as well solving your problem, but as mentioned above, the easier way to do it is with css.

```
var inst2 = document.getElementById("edit");
inst2.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){toggleEdit(true);})
inst2.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){toggleEdit(false);})
```

Comment: Then how does it work https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_leave_out ? Is it because the element in the middle (of the middle example in the link) is not an image?