# How to add photo over another photo in html

Tags: html, css, image

how can I add picture over another picture like this:
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <p><a href="" class="as">Начало</a> <a href="" class="as">За нас</a> <a href="" class="as">Промоции</a> <a href="" class="as">Контакти</a></p>
        <p class="moto">Веднъж хапни, за цял живот се пристрасти!</p>

    </div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.container-fluid {

    height: 470px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black, transparent 70px, transparent 330px, black, black 500px),url("images.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;


}
```

Comment: use `position` to align the image

Comment: You can set one img as html background and the other one as a normal img

Comment: Yes, I will be using position to align the image, but how I should add an image over another? I tried with <img src> but the picture hasn't loaded.

Comment: Is it a problem if I upload a .jpg file?

Comment: your img src tag should look something like this `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">` check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)  for more info on img tag

Comment: Yes, I did it. Now I have to position image. How will do this?

Comment: check out this post!!!! [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Comment: I solved my problem with using display:inline; ! Thanks to all!

Answer (score -1):

You might try using position, and also giving the image you want on top a z-index.