# Two images on each other with responsive behavior and proportional scaling

Tags: javascript, css, image, responsive-design, scaling

[image]I would like to do something pretty standard in HTML/CSS/javascript I think but somehow I didn't find any solution for now: I want to have multiple images on each other with some of them being clickable. For example:
[submarine with red circle button as window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wEdb.png) in this case the submarine is one img and the red circle is an `input type="image"` working as a button.

I want those multiple images to behave "as one" in term of responsivness and scaling so that I still see the same overall image independantly of the size of my window.

If I use this trick here: [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html) and make both images responsive then the circle is not scaling down simultanuously with the submarine. Moreover, since the red circle is positioned in an `absolute` way it is not staying at the same place relative to the submarine.

here is my current code:

```css
    .div{
    position: relative;
    }

    .responsive {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    #test2 {
    width: 12.3%;    
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 73%;
    top: 62%;
    }
    
    #test
    {
      width: 100%;    
      position:relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <img src="/submarine.png" id="test" class="responsive" />
      <input type="image" src="/red_circle.png"  id="test2" class="responsive" />
</div>
```

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question includes code that you could use as an example of what doesn't work. You could even use it as a basis for more attempts and research into the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Comment: no @Hykilpikonna unfortunately this solution does not answer my question. The answer from Manu below did partially. I still have the issue that my Website design is built with cards which are changing sizes depending on the window size but stepwise so not in a continuous resposnive way. Since the red circle is positioned in an absolute way in this card and the submarine in a relative way in the same card as soon as the card changes size the red circle is not positioned correctly anymore. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achive that, you can work with percentages, so if you reduce the scale of the window the size of the images reduce as well.

CSS:

```
.submarine {
  width: 30%;
  height: 55%;
  position: relative;
}

.redDot {
  width: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="submarine.jpg" clas="submarine">
  <img src="redDot.png" class="redDot">
</div>
```

Then play with the margins in orther to position the red dot in the submarine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Manu for your fast answer! It brought me a step closer to my goal. The issue I still have is that my Website design is built with cards which are changing sizes depending on the window size but stepwise so not in a continuous resposnive way. Since the red circle is positioned with an `absolute` way in this card and the submarine in a `relative` way in the same card as soon as the card changes size the red circle is not positioned correctly anymore. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I understand. The solution i've found it's simple, make relative the parent div (the one that contains the images) and move the images around with properties: `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` instead of using `margin`. I can make a snippet if you don't get what I'm saying

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm one step closer but I still have a weird behavior I think. I tried to describe it as good as possible. I attached a picture to my original post with the different window width of the website relative to the screen width do show you what I mean. I will try to add my current snippet too.

Comment: ok I think I managed to add the image and my current code as wished. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions and positions in percentages relate to the dimensions of the parent element. In your case the window of the submarine should be positioned as a percentage of the submarines dimensions. What you should do to make this is work is to put the window as a child in the submarine. Easiest would be to work with divs with background-images and use background-size: 100% to make the background-images scale with the elements.

Also you could use the "padding-bottom trick" to set the "height" of the div to a percentage of the parent's width.

```css
#submarine {
  background: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
 }
 
 #window{
   position: absolute;
   background: red;
   width: 20%;
   padding-bottom: 20%;
   right: 5%;
   top: 40%;
   background: red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="submarine">
  <div id="window"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnaks for your answer! I tested it but unfortunately I didn't manage to get what I wanted. I'm tried a solution using img area but it's not responsive without the use of a jquery which I want to avoid. No I'm looking for an easy way to create vector polyline in order to have responsive clickable areas. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: I think svg images would work better, they are build with vectors and scale almost automatically. I  made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/n5tz7vaq/ (svg drawing was made with https://editor.method.ac/). The "submarine" and red dot are in one svg but alternatively you could put them in different html-elements and use the svgs as background-images and use the technique in my answer. Then you could use an input element and use svg as a background (if you really need the input element). But an input element is always kind a rectangular (you can apply border-radius but that's about it).